Fitting models with known and unknown nonlinear shapes in R
I am trying to fit a model for hypothesis-testing in R using mgcv.
The response, Y is hypothesized to be a linear function of x1 and x2. This is a spatial dataset with some structure that is unknown to me a priori and so I additionally include a smooth term for latitude and longitude.
So far we have this model, expressed in R / mgcv syntax:
Y ~ x1 + x2 + s(Latitude, Longitude, k = someK, bs = "tp")

There are 2 other terms that I must add to this model. The first is a saturating curve characterized by 2 parameters, taking the form:
beta1 * ( (x3 ^ beta2) - 1) / beta2)

where beta1 and beta2 are the parameters to be estimated and x3 is a data vector. The next is an over-dispersion parameter / observation level random effect to absorb residual variance. Again in mgcv terms:
s(obs, bs="re")

First I wrote a model using nimble with all of these components represented. I mention this only to explain that it is not an option going forward. The model doesn't converge (or else is converging extremely slowly) and I think the samplers have some difficulty deciding where to attribute variance (either to the spatial smooth or to the over-dispersion parameter) even with informative priors. Fine, that was wishful thinking.
Next, I tried to fit a model with the nonlinear curve, without the spatial smooth, and with the over-dispersion term in brms; however, this model should account for spatial structure in some way. I can't seem to write smooth terms within a nonlinear model using brms. Here's the structure of the nonlinear brms formula via bf:
bf(Y ~ b0 + b1*x1 + b2*x2 + b3*( (x3 ^ b4) - 1) / b4), 
   b0 ~ (1|overdisp), b1 + b2 + b3 ~ 1, nl = TRUE)

where b0 is the global intercept with an additional over-dispersion parameter estimated for each observation around this mean. But again, I'm now missing the spatial structure of unknown form and complexity. I try a GAM using mgcv:
bam(Y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + s(Latitude, Longitude, k = someK, bs = "tp") + 
    s(overdisp, bs="re"), data = dat, ...)

This model runs, yields a sensible output, and gets 99% of deviance explained. All is well -- except I can't seem to include the nonlinear term with 2 parameters for x3. Is there some way to do this that I have missed in the documentation for mgcv? Or perhaps a way to express a GAM term in a nonlinear brms model? Or else is there some theoretical/statistical reason for why I shouldn't approach the modelling as I have?

Good question. This may be a question for Paul (brms developer). He is usually responsive to posts on the Stan forums (discourse.mc-stan.org) tagged as brms, or you could try opening an issue on the brms GitHub (https://github.com/paul-buerkner/brms/issues/)

Not really an answer to the question but for anyone stuck on a similar issue, I assigned the No U-Turn Sampler in nimbleHMC which takes longer per-iteration but achieved convergence in a fraction of the iterations required for the default random walk samplers. The fully parameterized model with all linear, nonlinear, smooth, and over-dispersion terms converged after this.
